# When writing to a terminal, get the current column number you are writing to

Tags: terminal, tty, javascript

In Node.js I can get the number of a columns of a terminal window using:

```
const cols = process.stdout.columns;
```

if the user shrinks the terminal during the process, the number of columns should shrink too, so you can re-read `process.stdout.columns` when the window resizes.

When I write to stdout, I use `process.stdout.write()`, is there some way using linux to determine which column number I am writing to?

For every character I write, I jump to a new column, until a new-line or I reach the end of the terminal window?

Comment: It is somehow possible to get the terminal size, but it's not really possible to tell where the cursor is.

Comment: You could do this with one of the node add-ons that uses the VT100 cursor position report, e.g., [this](https://github.com/chjj/blessed), but none of them appear to have any useful documentation: you'll have to read the source code to make use of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you mean by "some way using linux"?
If your terminal reacts to "VT102 and ECMA-48/ISO 6429/ANSI X3.64 terminal controls", you might be lucky printing "Cursor position report (CPR)" request: `ESC[6n` to it and reading the cursor coordinate answer `ESC[y;xR` "where x,y is the cursor location".

EDIT: c.f. `man console_codes`

Comment: A better thing to look at than that manual page is ECMA-48:1991 § 8.3.35.